# Are the Marek-knows tutorials any good or still relevant?

Tags: video

Anyone have any experience with this? This hasn't been refereed as mush as it 'looks/sound' like.

https://www.marekknows.com/

Among many other products, the site provides game engine development video, which is around *45hours long*. Starting from context creation, model loading, scene graph, animation. But it looks like a little old. Is it still useful?

Comment: That video series is as long as some game development competitions.

Comment: Ye, But it covers all the basics you need to know about while developing an engine. That's the intriguing part.

Comment: More accurately it *claims* to cover all the basics you need to know. I'm highly suspect of the content being worth the money.

Comment: I am looking for someone who has experience with this tutorial. May be for an absolute beginner it can provide a good head start.

Comment: Of course, what you could do is look at the titles for each section, and create your 'own' reference book for each chapter covered. It will be cheaper and you'll definately learn more.

Comment: From a glance it's using msvc 2008, and you say it's old? Most of the stuff that's still relevant today is older than any of us =)

Comment: @JariKomppa What did you get by old? There is no point in learning Fixed Function rendering pipeline, is there?

Comment: @iamcreasy Yes, there is. First, most of the stuff you need to learn are not really dependent on how you do rendering, and second, if you want to support low-end chips (such as intel's), shaders are still not there. All this said, I don't know if Marek's tutorials are good, I'm just answering your question of whether it's still relevant, and yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the section.  I can tell you for certain that any tutorials on C++, basic game development maths, and very basic network programming won't be particularly dated if they were complete and correct when these were written.  The fields just haven't changed much.

On the other hand, OpenGL has undergone a lot of changes recently.  Personally speaking, I wouldn't pay for a series of tutorials that covered OpenGL <2.0, since the fixed-function pipeline has been eliminated altogether in modern versions of both major graphics APIs.  So in that sense, yes, any OpenGL tutorial written without extensive use of shaders is going to be extremely dated.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally bought these tutorials, both the game engine tutorial and the alterative tutorial using the game engine to build a game (recently i have also got the networking tutorial as well)

In my personal opinion if you are wanting a set of tutorials to show you how to create a fantastically rendered terrain with prepass etc etc these tutorials are not for you.

However if you are looking for a solid introduction to game development with c++ look no further. The tutorials take you through the very basics of not only coding a game engine but understanding what you are doing and why you are doing it.

Yes they may be a bit out of date but then again everything is out of date the second its published.

I would certainly recommend then, i think the detail they go into is fantastic and definitely good value for money.

Comment: Is the engine is based on fixed function rendering? does it touch shader based?

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that it is worth the money. I bought it couple of years ago. Lost the disk and he still manages to answer all my questions straight away. He's a star and he knows his stuff.

I have learned plenty from his tutorials. Most of all his methods got me thinking outside the box in terms of how an engine should be programmed from the ground up.

I hope this helps

Chris